# Why invokes the constructor the overriden method instead of the one from his class?

Tags: java, scjp

By runnung the following code I got the result:


 method from class A

 method from class B.

```java
public class Test {

    static class A {

        public A() {
            someMethod();
        }

        public void someMethod() {
            System.out.println("method from class A");
        }
    }

    static class B extends A {
        public void someMethod() {
            System.out.println("method from class B");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new A();
        new B();
    }
}
```

The first line of the result is clear but the second one isn't. Why didn't the constructor of the class A call the method defined in class A instead the overriden method of class B? Can it be that after compilation the code from constructor A is somehow copied to class B so that we actually call our method from class B?

Comment: This is a significant difference between Java and C++. C++ behaves as you are expecting here. Java doesn't. You would have to ask James Gosling the reason why.

Comment: Im not that familiar with C++ anymore. Do C++ constructors call their parent constructors without explicitly being written to do so?  Is that what the o.p. is expecting?

Answer (score 3):

The second object is of type B, so when the method `someMethod` is invoked in the constructor, it takes the last method declaration of this method for type `B`.

Comment: Might want to mention polymorphism.